# Реализовать функцию возможности опечатки на JS

Tags: javascript

Есть поиск, он ищет в массиве, перебирает каждый элемент, сравнивая его с введенным значением.

Например не «Привет», а «Прибет» результат должен быть верный, но если разница больше 1 символ («Привет мир» и «Прибит мир») уже не верный.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Помогите реализовать функцию опечатки.

Comment: А проблема в чем?

Comment: не могу реализовать функцию опечатки

Comment: @kamshir: https://habr.com/ru/company/joom/blog/433554/